# Laravel Eloquent sum of column in another table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

so I have this output:

[image]

**Here is the code in my controller:**

```
public function showToday()
    {
        $now = new DateTime('today');
        $today = $now->format('Y-m-d');
        $reservations = Reservation::with('room') ->where('reservation_from', $now)
                                                            ->orderBy('created_at')
                                                            ->get();

        return \View::make('pages.admin.report.today') -> with('reservations', $reservations)
                                                       -> with('now', $today);
    }
```

**Schema:**

[image]

**View (blade)**

```
  <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Room #</th>
          <th>Reservation From</th>
          <th>Reservation To</th>
          <th>Booked At</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
      </thead>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
        @foreach($reservations as $res)
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $res -> room -> room_number }}</td>
          <td>{{ date('F d, Y', strtotime($res -> reservation_from)) }}</td>
          <td>{{ date('F d, Y', strtotime($res -> reservation_to)) }}</td>
          <td>{{ $res -> created_at }}</td>
          <td>{{ $res -> room -> price }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><!-- Display price total here --></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

**Reservation Model**

```
class Reservation extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'reservations';

    protected $fillable = ['roomNumber', 'clientId', 'reservation_from', 'reservation_to'];

    public function room() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Room');
    }

}
```

**Room model**

```
class Room extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'rooms';

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'roomNumber', 'type', 'price', 'description'];

    public function reservations() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Reservation', 'id', 'room_number');
    }
}
```

When I try to add this in my controller,

```
$sum = $reservations['room']->sum( 'price' );
dd($sum);
```

I get an `Undefined index: room`

What I wanted to is to display the total amount(sum) by adding the prices from the rooms table. How can I do that with Laravel and Eloquent? Thank you in advance.

Comment: whats the relation between your reservation and room? whats the first image you show us? you need to explain if that was another database table or just a view. make your question clear\

Comment: Why not simply sum in your view? Like define `$total = 0` before your loop, and then in your foreach `$total += $res->room->price`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$reservations->sum('room.price')`

Comment: Will try this in a bit

Comment: Strange, I've tested. Check it again.

Comment: Let me try again, seems I made a mistake in my db

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Great. Thanks you!